# Can you compare a combined string with a normal string?

Tags: php

I made a form script with captcha, here is a part of it:

```
<?php
$captcha1 = rand(0,9);
$captcha2 = rand(0,9);
$captcha3 = rand(0,9);
$captcha4 = rand(0,9);
$captcha5 = rand(0,9);
$captchafinal = $captcha1.$captcha2.$captcha3.$captcha4.$captcha5;
$captchaimageholder = array("captcha0.png", "captcha1.png", "captcha2.png", "captcha3.png", "captcha4.png", "captcha5.png", "captcha6.png", "captcha7.png", "captcha8.png", "captcha9.png");

print_r($captchafinal);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (!empty($_POST['afzender']) && !empty($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['inhoud']) && !empty($_POST['captcha']) )
    {
        echo $_POST['captcha'];
        if ($captchafinal == $_POST['captcha'])
        {
            echo "<div class='approved'>Succesvol verstuurd.</div>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class='error'>&Eacute;&eacute;n of meer velden zijn niet correct ingevuld.</div>";
    }
}
```

The statement `if ($captchafinal == $_POST['captcha'])` evaluates to false, but I don't know why.

Comment: What is in `$_POST['captcha']`

Comment: What does `var_dump($captchafinal, $_POST['captcha'])` output? Then you'll have your answer. From your code it seems like you're creating a *new* captcha when you check whether the captcha was correct. Instead, hash the captcha value and include it in your form, and then check if the hashed version of your POST data equals the posted hashed version of your captcha.

Comment: @Daan: It outputs the number.

Comment: I think @h2ooooooo already has your answer.

Comment: @h2ooooooo It outputs: `string(5) "08986" NULL 08986`

Comment: @RichardWeug Hence there is no such thing as `$_POST['captcha']` (`NULL`). `NULL =/= "08986"`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I found out that the script is indeed generating a new code when submitting the form. Will fix this with a session variable. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardWeug Glad you fixed it, and good idea about the session variable.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have problem with following. You call php script, choose random 5 number and show this 5 pictures to client. Client type what they see and call php again. php **AGAIN** choose 5 random numbers and compare it with user input. But script not compare numbers displayed to client but new generated set.